# Adding xml nodes at a specific point using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml and want to insert additional xml into it:

```
<root>
    <steps>
        <step name="step1" type="process">
            <steps>
                <step name="substep1">
                </step>
            </steps>
        </step>
        <step name="step2" type="process">
            <steps>
                <step name="substep1">
                <!-- more substeps...-->
                </step>
            </steps>
        </step>
        <step name="step3" type="process">
            <steps>
                <step name="substep1">
                </step>
                <step name="substep2">
                </step>
                <!-- more substeps...-->
            </steps>
        </step>
        <!-- THE BELOW IS WHAT I WISH TO ADD... and it has to be here -->
        <step name="reference">
            <!-- These stuff have been hardcoded in my xsl so its fine -->
        </step>
        <!-- ends -->
    </steps>
    <references>
        <reference name="reference1">
        </reference>
        .
        .
        .
    </references>
</root>
```

As I've written in the xml sample, I wish to add an additional step element as the very last step within the outter most steps.  I have the xml snippet already hardcoded in my xsl so all I needed to do is to find the best logic to move to that particular point of the xml tree so I can call the template and have that snipet added in.

What is the recommended/best approach to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete and simple solution -- explained in details. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pAddition">
   <step name="reference">
     <XXX/>
   </step>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/steps/step[position()=last()]">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$pAddition"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<root>
    <steps>
        <step name="step1" type="process">
            <steps>
                <step name="substep1">
                </step>
            </steps>
        </step>
        <step name="step2" type="process">
            <steps>
                <step name="substep1">
                <!-- more substeps...-->
                </step>
            </steps>
        </step>
        <step name="step3" type="process">
            <steps>
                <step name="substep1">
                </step>
                <step name="substep2">
                </step>
                <!-- more substeps...-->
            </steps>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <references>
        <reference name="reference1">
        </reference>
        .
        .
        .
    </references>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <steps>
      <step name="step1" type="process">
         <steps>
            <step name="substep1"/>
         </steps>
      </step>
      <step name="step2" type="process">
         <steps>
            <step name="substep1"><!-- more substeps...--></step>
         </steps>
      </step>
      <step name="step3" type="process">
         <steps>
            <step name="substep1"/>
            <step name="substep2"/><!-- more substeps...-->
         </steps>
      </step>
      <step name="reference">
         <XXX/>
      </step>
   </steps>
   <references>
      <reference name="reference1"/>
        .
        .
        .
    </references>
</root>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The *identity rule* is used to copy all nodes as is.
2. The XML fragment to be inserted is specified (for convenience) as the body of a global `xsl:param`. In a realistic application it will be in a separate xml file and will be obtained using the xslt `document()` function.
3. The template that matches the insertion point copies the matched node by calling the identity rule. then it copies the content of the `xsl:param` and thus the new conted is output exactly at the desired insertion point.

Comment: +1 Good answer. That's the way I would do. But I think it would easier to just copy the param RTF.

Comment: @Alejandro: Hey, where is the +1 :) ?  As for literal copying -- yes, but you and I both know well that we apply templates to achieve flexibility -- tomorrow someone may ask as to do some processing on the parameter contents, too.

Comment: @Alejandro: Actually, you were right. I simplified a lot the transformation -- see the edits.